# action bar still briefly pops up even though set to hidden

Tags: android

just a quick question. I am using `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` to hide the action bar in the main activity in on create, and even though I have a splash screen in hops that the action bar will be fully hidden, the action bar displays for a fraction of a second at startup and then goes away. I want it to be gone COMPLETELY! any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the `Activity` theme as `NoTitleBar` in manifest.

As an example,

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
```

Comment: thanks, yeah i didnt thank of that because when i tried to do something like that on other apps it changed the look of spinners and sliders. etc. thanks tho got it fixxed

Comment: had to wait the usual duration. accepted. but one more question. I had a spinner on that page (splash screen) and it doesnt look like the new er spinners kinda old. Does changing the theme like that like i was worried about have an effect on spinners? (making them look older or something)

Answer (score 0):

Android uses a default theme of the application to show at startup to create the impression that app starts immediately. Try to set apllication theme to

```
 <appication
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `requestWindowFeature(int)` **before** calling `setContentView(int)` in onCreate().